# Insert Padding for Specific Div Class

Tags: css, wordpress-gutenberg

I am definitely a newbie and trying to add some left and right padding for a blog archive page in a specific div.

Using inspect on the page, I know unchecking the padding or the max-width solves the problem. But for whatever reason, I cannot accomplish it.

```
.content-width-fullwidth .content-container.site-container {
max-width: none;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;}
```

Since I am using wordpress, I need to name this CSS so I can apply it to the specific page. Here is what I attempted, with no success:

```
blog.content-width-fullwidth .content-container.site-container {
max-width: none;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 100px;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<div class="content-container site-container">
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<div id="archive-container" class="content-wrap grid-cols post-archive grid-sm-col-2 grid-lg-col-3 item-image-style-above">
<article class="entry content-bg loop-entry post-1588 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-san-diego-vacation-rental-regulations tag-san-diego-vacation-rental-laws tag-san-diego-vacation-rental-licenses">
```

Any help, or suggestions, you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide HTML code please!

Comment: Here is a link to the website and specific page: https://www.titanbeachrentals.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

For your changes, just add the phrase "!important" to the end of the css code, like this :

```
padding: 0 !important;
```

Comment: Tried, but no change.

Comment: Please specify the exact location of the changes so I can help you further

Comment: I am attempting to add padding to the blog archive page on the left and right so that any blog excerpts which lead you to the blog have padding on the far left of the page and the far right. Currently there is no padding and h blog preview featured photo is directly aligned with the edge of the screen.

Comment: You must first create a class with name "custom_padding" and give it to div primary. `.custom_padding{ padding: 20px !important;}` ; `<div id="primary" class="content-area custom_padding">`

Comment: If it still does not work, let me know so I can write the full code for you.